# How can I send emails so that they appear to come from my hotmail account?

Tags: php, email

I am planning to send out a batch email to roughly 100 people - however I want to personalize it with their name and business name. I want to create a script in PHP so that I can loop through my data, insert the variables into the message, and send, in one go.

The only caveat is that I want the email to appear to have come from my hotmail account, I know I can add in 'From' headers using PHP's mail function, but nevertheless many of the recipient accounts will flag that the message has come from my apache server not the genuine hotmail account.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: The only way you can do that is to send them from your Hotmail account - otherwise, it'll be obvious from the headers that it's come from a third party server, and the headers you need to update for that are ones that you can't update yourself in PHP.

Comment: I believe that since email addresses are digitally signed your best (and probably only) option it to connect to hotmail via pop3 from and send the emails that way. s

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - POP is for retrieving email. SMTP would be the way to send. Or possibly in Hotmail's case, an Exchange server.

Comment: Yes I think I can use this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide//libraries/email.html - it allows for SMTP details to be entered and should work well for what I need.

Comment: I do not have permission to email the individuals in question - nevertheless I am not a spammer, just a curious developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to send your mail through hotmail's SMTP server.

You could probably adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748837/1084754) fairly easily to send mail using hotmail's servers instead of google's.

[Hotmail SMTP configuration info](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/hotmail/send-receive-email-from-mail-client)